# Proving that a reversible list is a palindrome in Coq

Tags: coq, palindrome, theorem-proving, logical-foundations

Here is my inductive definition of palindromes:

```
Inductive pal { X : Type } : list X -> Prop :=
  | pal0 : pal []
  | pal1 : forall ( x : X ), pal [x]
  | pal2 : forall ( x : X ) ( l : list X ), pal l -> pal ( x :: l ++ [x] ).
```

And the theorem I want to prove, from *Software Foundations*:

```
Theorem rev_eq_pal : forall ( X : Type ) ( l : list X ),
  l = rev l -> pal l.
```

My informal outlines of the proof are as follows:

> Suppose `l0` is an arbitrary list such that `l0 = rev l0`. Then one of the following three cases must hold. `l0` has:
>
> (a) zero elements, in which case it is a palindrome by definition.
>
> (b) one element, in which case it is also a palindrome by definition.
>
> (c) two elements or more, in which case `l0 = x :: l1 ++ [x]` for some element `x` and some list `l1` such that `l1 = rev l1`.
>
> Now, since `l1 = rev l1`, one of the following three cases must hold...
>
> The recursive case analysis will terminate for any finite list `l0` because the length of the list analyzed decreases by 2 through each iteration. If it terminates for any list `ln`, all of its outer lists up to `l0` are also palindromes, since a list constructed by appending two identical elements at either end of a palindrome is also a palindrome.

I think the reasoning is sound, but I'm not sure how to formalize it. Can it be turned into a proof in Coq? Some explanations of how the tactics used work would be especially helpful.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a nice example where "direct" induction does not work well at all because you don't directly make the recursive call on the tail, but on **part** of the tail. In such cases, I usually advice to state your lemma with the length of the list, not on the list itself. You can then specialize it. That would be something like:

```
Lemma rev_eq_pal_length: forall (X: Type) (n: nat) (l: list X), length l <= n -> l = rev l -> pal l.
Proof.
(* by induction on [n], not [l] *)
Qed.

Theorem rev_eq_pal: forall (X: Type) (l: list X), l = rev l -> pal l.
Proof.
(* apply the previous lemma with n = length l *)
Qed.
```

I can help you in more detail if necessary, just leave a comment.

Good luck !

V.

EDIT: just to help you, I needed the following lemmas to make this proof, you might need them too.

```
Lemma tool : forall (X:Type) (l l': list X) (a b: X),                                                                                                         
            a :: l = l' ++ b :: nil -> (a = b /\ l = nil) \/ exists k, l = k ++ b :: nil.

Lemma tool2 : forall (X:Type) (l1 l2 : list X) (a b: X),                                                                                                         
     l1 ++ a :: nil = l2 ++ b :: nil -> a = b /\ l1 = l2.
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also derive your induction principle from a form of well-founded induction.

```
Notation " [ ] " := nil : list_scope.
Notation " [ x1 ; .. ; x2 ] " := (cons x1 .. (cons x2 nil) ..) : list_scope.
Open Scope list_scope.

Conjecture C1 : forall t1 f1 p1, (forall x1, (forall x2, f1 x2 < f1 x1 -> p1 x2) -> p1 x1) -> forall x1 : t1, p1 x1.
Conjecture C2 : forall t1 p1, p1 [] -> (forall x1 l1, p1 ([x1] ++ l1)) -> forall l1 : list t1, p1 l1.
Conjecture C3 : forall t1 p1, p1 [] -> (forall x1 l1, p1 (l1 ++ [x1])) -> forall l1 : list t1, p1 l1.
Conjecture C4 : forall t1 (x1 x2 : t1) l1, length l1 < length ([x1] ++ l1 ++ [x2]).

Theorem T1 : forall t1 p1,
  p1 [] ->
  (forall x1, p1 [x1]) ->
  (forall x1 x2 l1, p1 l1 -> p1 ([x1] ++ l1 ++ [x2])) ->
  forall l1 : list t1, p1 l1.
Proof.
intros t1 p1 h1 h2 h3.
induction l1 as [l1 h4] using (C1 (list t1) (@length t1)).
induction l1 as [| x1 l1] using C2.
eapply h1.
induction l1 as [| x2 l1] using C3.
simpl.
eapply h2.
eapply h3.
eapply h4.
eapply C4.
Qed.
```

You can prove conjecture `C1` by first applying the hypothesis to the conclusion, then using structural induction on `f1 x1`, and then using some facts about `<`.

To prove `C3`, which has no induction hypothesis, you first use case analysis on `is_empty l1`, and then use the facts `is_empty l1 = true -> l1 = []` and `is_empty l1 = false -> l1 = delete_last l1 ++ [get_last l1]` (`get_last` will need a default value).