# Proving that a reversible list is a palindrome in Coq without exists tactic

Tags: exists, palindrome, coq

For an exercise in software foundation I want to prove the following theorem :

`Theorem rev_pal {X:Type} : forall (l:list X), l = rev l -> pal l.`

pal is defined as follow :

```
Inductive pal {X:Type} : list X -> Prop :=
| pal_nil : pal []
| pal_one : forall x, pal [x]
| pal_rec : forall x l, pal l -> pal (snoc(x:: l) x).
```

However to proove this I want to use a lemma using `exists` to say for exemple something like :

`foral (l l':list X) (a b:X), a::l = l' ++[b] -> (a=b /\ l=[]) \/ exists k, l = k ++ [b].`

In fact, I want to mention something little than l. But using the `destruct` tactic doesn't seems to help.

Why I don't want to use `exists` is because during the reading of the book software foundation, we don't have seen yet `exists`. Of course, one could tell me that `exists` can be seen as a `forall`, but it's hard to use in this form.

So how to prove this theorem without a such lemma ? I'm stuck.

Comment: How is `pal` defined? Please provide all definitions so that we can type your theorem on our machine and work with it.

Comment: I think you mean ``exists k, l = k ++ [b]`` in your example

Comment: Vinz : thanks for the typo.

@Gilles : I added a definition for pal. We can also define pal with rev. I don't know if one definition is better than an other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it has been said before, It is easier to prove this theorem using the length of the list :

```
Theorem rev_pal_aux {X:Type} : forall (l:list X) (n:nat) , length l<= n -> l = rev l -> pal l.
```

Then you can start an induction on n.

The key point to avoid something with *exists* is to use an inversion. For this proof it is possible to use an inversion on something like `x::l=rev x::l` and then a destruct on `rev l` (for some l). This way, you will get `x :: l = snoc (x0 :: l0) x` (l0 is new).

(l0) is the key. It is on l0 that you need to use the induction hypothesis.

Finally, I used the following lemma (not so easy to proof) :

```
Lemma length_snoc_aux {X:Type} : forall (l m:list X) (n:nat) (x:X), length l <= n -> l = snoc m x -> length m <= n.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't prove your theorem by direct induction on `l`.

For the inductive step, the induction hypothesis is `pal l` (after clearing the antecedent) and you're trying to prove `pal (x :: l)`.
But the induction hypothesis clearly contradicts the conclusion (unless `repeat x n = l`), and so it's unusable.

Seeing that until this point in the book there's been no mention of fancier kinds of induction and that this is a 5 star exercise, I think it's safe to conclude that you have more freedom with this exercise.

Take a look at [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24363319/).

Comment: Thanks ! I already seen this before posting here. But it's so frustrating to do an exercice and realize after that you need tools not mentionned in the book. Because even with an induction on n, I still need something like "exists" I guess.